# Custom BooleanField name in Django admin list filter

Tags: python, django, filter, boolean, django-admin

In Django admin I can change default True/False representation of `BooleanField` using `choices` argument. It appears in object page and list page. But it doesn't changes in admin list filter. Why? How can I change defaults 'All/Yes/No/Unknown' in `list_filter`?

app/models.py

```
CHOICES_BUILDING_CONDITION = (
    (True, 'New'),
    (False, 'Old'),
    (None, 'Unknown'),
)

class Flat(models.Model):
    is_new_building = models.BooleanField(
        'Building condition', null=True, blank=True, choices=CHOICES_BUILDING_CONDITION
)
```

app/admin.py

```
class FlatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('is_new_building', )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replicate its behavior with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

NEW_BUILDING_MAPPING = {'true': True, 'false': False, 'none': None}


class NewBuildingListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('New building')
    parameter_name = 'is_new_building'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('true', _('New')),
            ('false', _('Old')),
            ('none', _('Unknown')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        val = self.value()
        if val is not None:
            return queryset.filter(is_new_building=NEW_BUILDING_MAPPING[val])
        return queryset
```

and then plug in this filter with:

```
class FlatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (NewBuildingListFilter,)
```